# Can an inline function in a header file use a constant which has internal linkage?

Tags: c++, constants, inline, linkage, one-definition-rule

Consider the following code:

```
const int a = 0;
const std::string b = "hi";

inline void f_a1()
{
    std::cout << a;
}

inline void f_b1()
{
    std::cout << b;
}

inline void f_a2()
{
    std::cout << &a;
}

inline void f_b2()
{
    std::cout << &b;
}
```

Assume this code exists in a header file that will be included in multiple translation units.

My understanding of inline functions is that they must be exactly the same in every translation unit.

My understanding of constants as used above, is that they are implictly `static` ie internal linkage. These means each translation unit gets its own copy.

As the inline functions above rely on these constants, which of these functions, if any, are correct?

Comment: `f_a1` and `f_b1` are correct, because they refer to the value of a constant. Even if the compiler creates more than one constant, they will all have the same value. So, even if different occurrences of the functions use different actual constants, it will not break the expectations for the code (btw. most compiler will fold the `int` constant directly in the generated code, so there will be no actual `a` constant in your program). I'm thinking about the other two.

Comment: @GiulioFranco why would `f_a2` pr `f_b2` be incorrect?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I did not say they are. I'm thinking about it. If the constants are really statically linked (which I'm not sure of) then the compiler might end up having different instances of them, which will have different addresses, unless the linker is able to unify the different definitions (which should be the case).

Comment: @GiulioFranco I expect the addresses to be different. Why would that be a problem?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore see the answer by ecatmur.

Comment: @GiulioFranco: In C++03 all four would be illegal as the text requires what Neil mentions: not only the text of the functions must be the same in all translation units, also the interpretation including what each one of the identifiers resolves to. When included in two translation units, `a` will resolve to two different objects and even if the two definitions have the same semantics they are not *one*.  The rules for constant expressions were changed in C++11, and I am not so sure what the current state is... I believe, not sure, that in C++11 `f_a1` might be valid, I don't think the rest are

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If included into multiple translation units, the only function that is valid is `f_a1`.

The relevant clause is **[basic.def.odr]**/6, which states that an `inline` function can appear in multiple translation units, but only given that:

> [...] a name can refer to a non-volatile
>   `const` object with internal or no linkage if the object has the same literal type in all deﬁnitions of D,
>   and the object is initialized with a constant expression (5.19), and the object is not odr-used, and the
>   object has the same value in all definitions of D;

As the objects are `const`, they have internal linkage per **[basic.link]**/3:

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is the name of [...]
>   — a non-volatile variable that is explicitly declared const or constexpr and neither explicitly declared
>   extern nor previously declared to have external linkage [...]

However, taking the address of or forming a reference to a variable (e.g. for argument passing) is *odr-use*, so `f_a2` and `f_b2` are invalid.  `f_b1` is also invalid, as the `ostream` output operator for `std::string` takes its argument by reference; and even if it took its argument by value the implicitly called copy constructor would take *its* argument by reference.  `f_a1` is OK because the `int` stream-out operator takes its argument by value, and copying the value of an `int const` is not odr-use.

Comment: I'm not sure that holds for `int const`.

Comment: `f_a1` does not *odr-use* the `a` constant, if you replace the constant with: `struct T { const int a = 0; }; /* no definition */` the code should still compile fine as `std::cout << T::a` does not *odr-use* `T::a`

Comment: 3.2/2 *A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is odr-used unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression (5.19) and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is immediately applied*, since the operator used is: `basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(int n);` the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied immediately and this use is not *odr-use*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas ah, good point. So `f_a1` is OK, but the rest are invalid.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Do you mean static const in your struct?