# const global variable in namespace

Tags: c++

I know that `static` `const` `class` members can be initialised in headers only. Is it the same for namespaces ? For example, is it valid to write :

**`namehuman.hpp`**

```
namespace namehuman
{
   string const human("human");
}
```

**`main.cpp`**

```
#include "namehuman.hpp"
cout << namehuman::human << endl;
```

I am wondering if all files including the header file will have their own copy of `string` human, or if human will be a true global variable (not copied many times). In order to avoid each including file making its copy, am I obliged to use `extern` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Constants have internal linkage. Thus any compilation unit that includes the header with the definition of the constant will have its own instance of the object.

According to the C++ Standard (3.5 Program and linkage)

> 3 A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is
>   the name of

...

> — a non-volatile variable that is explicitly declared const or
>   constexpr and neither explicitly declared extern nor previously
>   declared to have external linkage; or

If you want a constant with external linkage, you must declare it with the specifier `extern`, and define it in a compilation unit.

Answer (score 2):

I think that will define the `human` several times, so it can happen that this causes an ODR violation (see below). It's usually best to only declare it in the header

```
extern const string human;
```

and add the definition to the implementation file

```
string human("human");
```

Be careful about the initialization order fiasco and the equivalent when closing the application.

An ODR violation can be caused when an inline function with external linkage ODR-uses `human`. I think that, since that is really easy to do and there is no way to guard against it, it is best to define constant strings in the implementation file.

Comment: Although `human` will be defined several times, it is not an ODR violation because the definitions have internal linkage.  Your suggested change , it's unclear whether it is an improvement or not, and may even slow down the code; as well as introducing fiasco where there was previously none.

Comment: @Florian, because while your code "works", it's a wrong answer (BTW, I didn't downvote).  See the other answer.

Comment: I said it can happen that this causes an ODR violation: If an inline function accesses the string stored in `human` it is ODR-used, but if something is ODR used it is required that there is only one definition.

Comment: It cannot happen that this causes an ODR violation. Each translation unit's `human` is a different object, each such object has exactly one definition. (See [basic.link]/2, the definition of *internal linkage* is that names from other units cannot refer to it)

Comment: @M.M, that's exactly the problem. If an inline function uses a different object depending on the translation unit you get an ODR violation. (See [basic.dev.odr]/3, Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used
in that program.)

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766075/can-an-inline-function-in-a-header-file-use-a-constant-which-has-static-linkage/) seems to be about what you are describing.  I think it'd be good for your answer to say something like "this variable cannot be used in an inline function", as that is the only problem, and it could be said that the bug would be with the inline function, not with `human`.

Comment: I removed my link, yours is better.