# Linking error due to constness of the pointer array in C++03/C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, linker-errors, compiler-bug

This issue is reproducible in the g++ prior to `-std=c++14`. A linking error is generated due to highlighted `const` shown in below codes. It disappears, if the RHS `const` is removed.

```
/* main.cpp */
const char* const arr[2] = {"Hello", "World"};
//          ^^^^^
int main () {}
```

and

```
/* foo.cpp */
extern const char* const arr[2];
//                 ^^^^^
const char* foo () { return arr[0]; }
```

While compiling: `g++ [-std=c++11] main.cpp foo.cpp`, it gives following linking error:

```
In function `foo()': undefined reference to `arr'
```

Is it a compiler bug or a language limitation/feature?

Comment: `const` variables at namespace scope [are implicitly `static`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402177/const-global-variable-in-namespace), unless you add `extern`. I'm not sure why the behaviour changes with `-std=c++14`.

Comment: Shouldn't `extern const char* const arr[2];` be in a header file that both `main.cpp` and `foo.cpp` include?

Comment: @Quentin I am not sure why OP says pre c++14, g++ 5.1.0 produces error in any mode (c++14 c++17), your comment should be the answer

Comment: Cannot replicate on GCC 6.1, the behavior is consistent across all `std` flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noticed by Quentin, the draft n4296 is explicit about that in chapter 3.5 Program and linkage [basic.link] §3 (emphasize mine)

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is the name of
>   (3.1) — a variable, function or function template that is explicitly declared static; or,
>   (3.2) — **a variable of non-volatile const-qualified type** that is neither explicitly declared extern nor previously
>   declared to have external linkage;

When you declare `arr` to be const, it is implicitely given internal linkage. The fix is trivial:

```
/* main.cpp */
extern const char* const arr[2] = {"Hello", "World"};
```

But best practice would recommend to have `extern const char* const arr[2];` in a header included in all files using `arr` in order to correctly share the declaration and then add in one of those files `const char* const arr[2] = {"Hello", "World"};`, effectively yielding:

```
/* main.cpp */
extern const char* const arr[2]; // directly or more likely through an include...
...
const char* const arr[2] = {"Hello", "World"};
```